# From multiple video files to single output

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

Let's say that I have a list of hundreds of possible video files. Using `ffmpeg` it's pretty easy to take multiple files and stitch them together to single video output, but that's where the things become tricky.

I'm looking for a way to have them **stream live** and dynamically **add videos** to queue as stream goes on. Think of something like [SSAI](https://www.adpushup.com/blog/what-is-server-side-ad-insertion-and-how-does-it-work/) but for the whole video.

*Stream live* is there so we don't have a delay while waiting for `ffmpeg` to finish the whole video but rather start as soon as possible, and also so we could choose next files in queue during the live stream.

Simplified, it would look something like this:

```
[v] [v] [v] [v] - stored video files, eg. on S3 

      [v] - chosen file

      | | 
      | | - during the live stream
      | |
      \ /
       V    
   _________             ___________              ___________
   \       /             |         |              ||       ||
    \     /    =====>    |         |    =====>    ||  |:>  ||
     \___/               |_________|              ||_______||
  Video queue              FFMPEG?                Live stream
                      Transcoding module?
                            Magic?
```

I'm writing this in Node.js if that makes any difference.

Is this even possible? If you need any more information please ask away, and every suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do all videos have the same properties - codec, resolution ..etc?

Comment: The aim is for that to be true

Comment: Provided that is true, it can be done using a slightly complicated way.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction because I'm new in this field? It would really mean a lot!

Comment: You should be able to achieve that with "live playlist" feature of Unreal Media Server. You don't need any ffmpeg or transcoding, if all your files are encoded the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This looks useful, however it's only for Windows and we're running our app on Linux machines. Do you by any chance have any other ideas?

Comment: @Gyan, do you have any tips? I've been stuck here unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The basic method to do this is using 2 levels of the concat demuxer and looping the top-level concat input.

Create two text files.

root.txt:

```
file nested.txt
file nested.txt
```

nested.txt:

```
file current-video.mp4
```

and then,

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i root.txt -c copy {output options}
```

Update nested.txt with new filename **before** the playing of the current file ends.

FFmpeg git version > Jan 2019 or 4.2+ is required.

All files must have streams with identical encoding. Timebase for streams should be the same. Duration of all streams within a file should be the same, in order to maintain sync.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this ASAP

Comment: how to be able to do it with different videos with different encodings outputting a ts file suitable for dvb broadcasting?

Comment: You then have to re-encode all files to the same parameters before adding it.