# how to create a radio or video "station" continuous TS stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, continuous

I can't find any answer to this scenarios:

Produce a continuous ts file that initially contains silence (or blank video), and as I add files to a text file I wish them to be queued in the output ts stream.
Think of it as a radio or tv station.
I found everything on how to stream anything to anything,
but not a tv/radio broadcast like stream.

A good start seems to be this:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -nostats -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -fflags +genpts -f concat -i list.txt -map 0:a? -map 0:v? -map 0:s? -strict -2 -dn -c copy -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 /var/www/html/showname_.m3u8
```

> list.txt example

```
file '/mnt/vusolo-tv/show/Season 1/S01E01.mp4'
file '/mnt/vusolo-tv/show/Season 1/S01E02.mp4'
```

But i think there can be better ways...

This is not a good answer either: [From multiple video files to single output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143892/from-multiple-video-files-to-single-output)
because "All files must have streams with identical encoding. Timebase for streams should be the same. Duration of all streams within a file should be the same, in order to maintain sync."
And I want to be able to add arbitrary files and produce a TS stream playable by any TV (once broadcasted in dvb).

Comment: I implemented something similar once, you want a pipeline where you add new content to an encoding queue to generate one or more (if you plan to support adaptive streaming as well) MPEG-TS aligned variants with common encoding parameters. You then dynamically add them to the stream.

Comment: @aergistal yep. can you help?

Comment: @aergistal I just wish to produce a continuous ts stream (which will then be broadcasted) and insert new content... if the stream "runs out of content" a black stream or a fixed image should be shown. That's it.

Comment: you're trying to emulate an entire encoder/multiplexer workflow in software, this is not something that can be answered in a SO post. As a starting point for MPEG-TS manipulation you can take a look at VideoLAN's [multicat](https://www.videolan.org/projects/multicat.html) tool.